# Callback at the end of a Quartz trigger

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm considering using Quartz for an app but I need to get called back also when a triggered event ends (e.g. at the beginning I want to start and at the end to stop something). Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can get notified with [TriggerListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/TriggerListener.html) and [JobListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobListener.html)